# Keep backslash and linebreak with EOF

Tags: shell

I'm creating a file with `EOF` like this:

```
cat <<EOF > Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
    bsdtar \
    git \
    locales
EOF
```

But the result is:

```
RUN apt-get update -y   && apt-get install -y     bsdtar     git     locales
```

I want to keep the backslash and the linebreak

Comment: Double the backslashes; or quote-or-backslash the EOF (or any char(s) in it) to prevent all modification of the heredoc. [See the bash manual section on heredocs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to quote the EOF token:

```
cat <<"EOF" > Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
    bsdtar \
    git \
    locales
EOF
```

If you want to expand variables too, you need to escape the backslashes and not use any quotes.

Here's the corresponding `man bash` section.

```
      [n]<<[-]word
              here-document
      delimiter

   No  parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
   expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any part  of
   word  is  quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word,
   and the lines in the  here-document  are  not  expanded.   If  word  is
   unquoted,  all  lines  of  the here-document are subjected to parameter
   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  charac‐
   ter  sequence  \<newline>  is  ignored, and \ must be used to quote the
   characters \, $, and `.
```

Comment: But what do I have to do if I need to use some variables (not shown in my example code)?

Comment: They will get expanded as in the common shell double quoting. If this is not desired, use single quotes, eg. `cat <<'EOF' > Dockerfile`.

Comment: I think that's not the case (i.e. with double quotes around `EOF`, the variables will not be expanded). Are you sure? The correct answer is in the comment by @dave_thompson_085 : double the backslashes.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos I thought so, but it looks like I was wrong.

Comment: @user3142695 As in the comment above, double quoting stops expansion too. So to both expand variables and keep the backslashes, you need to escape the backslashes and not use any quotes.

Comment: I was trying to escape the backslashes and no matter what I tried it didn't work; the single quote trick did it and as a bonus, I no longer have to escape the `$variables` too! Thank you so much!